# I want to get client-ip either client is connected to LAN or WIFI using java script

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I want to get client-ip either client is connected to LAN or WIFI using java script, currently i am using following code:

```
function  getUserIP(onNewIP) {
// compatibility for firefox and chrome
let myPeerConnection = window['RTCPeerConnection'] || window['mozRTCPeerConnection'] || window['webkitRTCPeerConnection'];
let pc = new myPeerConnection({
iceServers: []
}),
noop = function () { },
localIPs = {},
ipRegex = /([0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}|[a-f0-9]{1,4}(:[a-f0-9]{1,4}){7})/g,
key;

function iterateIP(ip) {
if (!localIPs[ip]) onNewIP(ip);
localIPs[ip] = true;
}

// create a bogus data channel
pc.createDataChannel("");

// create offer and set local description
pc.createOffer(function (sdp) {
sdp.sdp.split('\n').forEach(function (line) {
if (line.indexOf('candidate') < 0) return;
line.match(ipRegex).forEach(iterateIP);
});

pc.setLocalDescription(sdp, noop, noop);
}, noop);

// listen for candidate events
pc.onicecandidate = function (ice) {
if (!ice || !ice.candidate || !ice.candidate.candidate || !ice.candidate.candidate.match(ipRegex)) return;
ice.candidate.candidate.match(ipRegex).forEach(iterateIP);
};
}
let ipAddr = [];
this.getUserIP(function (ip) {
ipAddr.push(ip);
localStorage['ip'] = ipAddr[0];
});
```

This code is working for older version of chrome but not working for latest chrome (Version 80).

Comment: _“This code is working in older version of chrome but not working in latest chrome (Version 80)”_ - probably because exposing the IP address of the client via WebRTC is considered a _leak_ to begin with, in most circumstances.

Comment: You need to show what the exact issue is, try add a screenshot of the error message you're getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome 76+
Last year I successfully discover my local IP via JavaScript. However, recent Chrome updates (76?) have worked this method so that it now returns an obfuscated IP, such as: 1f4712db-ea17-4bcf-a596-105139dfd8bf.local

If you have full control over your browser, you can undo this behaviour by turning it off in Chrome Flags, by typing this into your address bar:

chrome://flags
and DISABLING the flag Anonymize local IPs exposed by WebRTC

In my case, I require the IP for a TamperMonkey script to determine my present location and do different things based on my location. I also have full control over my own browser settings (no Corporate Policies, etc). So for me, changing the chrome://flags setting does the trick.

Sources:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/discuss-webrtc/6stQXi72BEU

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/webrtc-web/index.html

Comment: This is the right answer! The only thing to note is these flags will *probably* be going away eventually (I am not on the Google WebRTC team, so I don't control anything)